# Creating associations between models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize.js to create some tables. The models are User, Shop, Role and ShopUserRoles.

I have declared the models in the `models/` folder like:

User.js

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey : true
        },
        fullName : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'full_name',
            allowNull : false
        },
    }, {
        tableName: 'users',

        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.ShopUserRoles, {foreignKey: 'user_id' });
            }
        },
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt : 'created_at',
        updatedAt : 'updated_at'
    });

    return User;
};
```

Shop.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Shop = sequelize.define('Shop', {
        id : {
            type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique : true,
            primaryKey : true
        },
        shopName : {
            type : DataTypes.STRING,
            field : 'shop_name',
            allowNull : false
        },
        status : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    }, {
        tableName : 'shops',

        classMethods : {
            associate : function(models) {
                Shop.hasMany(models.ShopUserRoles, {foreignKey : 'shop_id'});
            }
        },
        timestamps : true,
        createdAt : 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    });

    return Shop;
};
```

Role.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
        id : {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name : {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName : 'roles',

        classMethods : {
            associate : function(models) {
                Role.hasMany(models.ShopUserRoles, {foreignKey: 'role_id'});
            }
        },
        timestamps : true,
        createdAt : 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    });

    return Role;
};
```

ShopUserRoles.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var ShopUserRoles = sequelize.define('ShopUserRoles', {
    }, {
        tableName : 'shop_user_roles',

        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                ShopUserRoles.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id' });
                ShopUserRoles.belongsTo(models.Shop, {foreignKey : 'shop_id'});
                ShopUserRoles.belongsTo(models.Role, {foreignKey: 'role_id'});
            }
        },
        timestamps : true,
        createdAt : 'created_at',
        updatedAt : 'updated_at'
    });

    return ShopUserRoles;
};
```

And I've imported them using `sequelize['import'](FILENAME)` format and added corresponding associations.

Now, as we have added associations, table `shop_user_roles` should be created AFTER the first three tables are generated, otherwise foreign key adding would not work. However, I am seeing that Sequelize is trying to create this table before `users` table is created. To remedy this, I have three options:

- Assigning associations only AFTER the tables have been created
- Assigning an explicit ordering of table creation or let Sequelize 'figure' things out intelligently
- Trying to do the whole thing twice (which is clumsy and I wouldn't want it in development code)

As for the first two options, I am not exactly sure how to do those using Sequelize.js. Any kind of reference or help would be much appreciated.

I am using Sequelize.js v3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed to solve this problem. Unfortunately it is a brute force attempt.

In my application, I was trying to export an array containing model names while maintaining the correct order. While we can get the associations between the models using the `associate` class method, it is also possible to hard-code the serial of table creation inside the `classMethods` property of models. For the `User` model, that could be like

```
classMethods: {
    serial: 1,
    associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.ShopUserRoles, {foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    }
}
```

Afterwards, a simple sort based on the hardcoded serial on the array containing these model names could do the trick.

Using the associations in order to make a Topologically sort would be a nicer approach as well.